Better Scientific notation for Bokeh/Holoviews
I am trying to make a dashboard with holoviews/bokeh and some numbers are rather large. This triggers the scientific notation ticks (ex.1.00e+4 ... 2.00e+5). I don't like the looks of that so I would like to implement one of 2 things and can't seem to get either to work.
Option 1: Display ticks in the form of 2.0x105, or even 2.0E5.
Option 2: I can divide my data by 104 and change my axis labels to say "X x104.
For option 1, I can't figure out how to do this with a Bokeh tickformatter to give to holoviews. It looks like I need to use the CustomJSTickFormatter, but I do not know javascript so this doesn't help me.
For option 2: Every time I try to use LaTeX or MathML as a label string, it truncates the label and fails to render it.
Here's my minimal reproducible code:
bokeh.__version__ = 3.6.1
holoviews.__version__ = 1.20.0
x = np.linspace(start=0, stop=100000, num=25)
y = np.linspace(start=0, stop=35, num=25)
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y': y, 'x2':x/10000})
hv.Points(df_test, ['x2', 'y']).opts(xlabel=r'$$\text{ This is messed up } \times 10^6$$')

Output with Option 2:

Option 2 is probably my preferred solution if I can get it to render correctly.

For option 2, see https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/issues/5740#issuecomment-2515666452 -- LaTeX appears to be working for pure Bokeh and for HoloViews+Matplotlib but not for HoloViews+Bokeh.

The code above works for me using bokeh 3.6.2 and holoviews 1.20.0. I want to mention, that I always delete the chached versions of bokeh and holoviews in the browser if an update is available. This avoids version conflicts which can be the reson for the output in the figure posted by the OP.

Well, given James's answer, I came up with a workaround for my needs...Unicode!

    import holoviews as hv
    
    # create a dictionary to convert numbers to superscripts
    super_dict = {1:'\u00b1',
                  2:'\u00b2',
                  3:'\u00b2',
                  4:'\u2074',
                  5:'\u2075',
                  6:'\u2076',
                  7:'\u2077',
                  8:'\u2078',
                  9:'\u2079',
                  0:'\u2070'}
    
    # use some math to find the closest power of 10 that is below your
    # desired max. In my case, I wanted 10 rather than 1. One could also
    # probably modify this use %3 to cut off at some reasonable thousand
    def simplify_data(data, col):
        import math
        import numpy as np
        logscale = math.floor(np.log10(data[col].max()))
        new_data = data[col]/(10**(logscale-1))
        new_label = f'{col}/10{super_dict[logscale-1]}'
        data.loc[:, [new_label]] = new_data
        return data, new_label
    
    # create synthetic data
    x = np.linspace(start=0, stop=200000, num=25)
    y = np.linspace(start=0, stop=35, num=25)
    df_test = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y': y})

    # run my new function to generate my scaled variable
    df_test, new_col = simplify_data(df_test, 'x')
    hv.Points(df_test, [new_col, 'y'])
    # the .opts(xlabel=...) is now not needed either



Clever approach!

Thank you, it obviously fails for any powers greater than 9, or negative powers, but that could probably be "easily" solved with a function to split up the number by the symbol/digit an then join them back together. Not efficient, but it works for now haha.
